# Integration of $\int\limits_{ -\infty }^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2/2} \; dx$.

Tags: probability

$$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  x^2 e^{-x^2/2} \; dx = -xe^{-x^2/2} \Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} \; dx,$$

$ = 0 + \sqrt{2\pi}.$

Is this calculation valid?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a correct use of integration by parts.

Comment: For a very elementary student, you would do integration by parts on the integral $a$ to $b$, then take limits as $a \to -\infty, b \to +\infty$.  But beyond a first course, we would know how to do this limit, and instead write what you have written.